# Can I use four monitors with a dual-link dual-DVI card?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, dvi, gpu

I plan to get this card, a [Gigabyte GTS 450](http://www.ebuyer.com/238428-gigabyte-gts-450-1gb-gddr5-dual-dvi-mini-hdmi-out-pci-e-graphics-gv-n450-1gi).

Apparently it has two DVI ports which support dual-link.  Does that mean I can plug in two DVI monitors per port, i.e. four monitors creating one big desktop?

If this is correct, will I be able to connect my four 19" monitors which run at 1280x1024, giving me a full desktop resolution of 5120x1024?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Dual-Link DVI works the opposite way around. It is used to send more data across a single DVI cable. This is used for monitors with very large resolutions (such as 30" monitors with a resolution of 2560x1600) as normal (single link) DVI doesn't have a high enough bandwidth to support a resolution that high.

The maximum number of monitors you will be able to use with that card is three, two for the two DVI ports and one in the mini HDMI.

Comment: The description "two DVI cables into a single monitor" is very misleading. Dual-DVI uses two data connections in a single cable. Both connections act as a team for doubling the available bandwidth for sending data to the monitor.

Comment: @Robert Hmm... I thought it was actually two cables. Looked it up, your right. It just sends more data across a single cable. Thanks for the correction.