# How to connect 3 monitors to GeForce GT720 using digital connection

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce, display-adapter

I have a [GeForce GT720 card](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-720/specifications).

As it said there, it supports up to 3 displays, and the remark at the bottom of specs table says:

- 3840x2160 at 30Hz.
- 4096x2160 at 24Hz supported over HDMI.
- 3840x2160 at 60Hz supported over DisplayPort.

But GT720 doesn't have a DisplayPort, it has one D-SUB, one dual-link DVI-D, and one HDMI port.

So, how can I connect 3 monitors to this video card? What cables and adapters I have to buy? The preferred way, is of course to avoid using D-SUB, and connect all them through digital ports.

**ADDED:** Card is [Inno3D model](http://www.inno3d.com/products_detail.php?refid=52), I see there really can be differences depending on card manufacturer. Ok, then I'll need some more research, and then there is another question, which should be asked separately - does dual-link DVI-D mean, it can handle two monitors through DVI port, using some kind of adapter?

**ADDED:** just in case, to save someone's time, as of [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/356923/can-i-use-four-monitors-with-a-dual-link-dual-dvi-card) - **no**, it can not, and is used for another purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without DisplayPort I'd be surprised if you could output to 3 screens without using the D-Sub connection. Provided your monitors support DVI, HDMI and VGA, have you tried using each of those cable types and connecting it in that way?

Which manufacturer is your graphics card? Certain models by different brands sometimes have different connections. For example, an MSI model might have DisplayPort where an EVGA doesn't or vice versa.

Comment: Thank you! Now I should go do some research about dual-link DVI. I have updated the question.